# Duplicate variable on entity in SQL Data Modeler

Tags: database-design, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm a complete beginner in SQL Data Modeler and I am trying to create a logical model . I have an airline entity with an `airline_id` and a `country name` and a city entity with a `city name`  and the `country name` . All are domain variables.
I use 1:N relation to connect the two entities.

[image]

However now that they are connected when I click on city I get that city has 4 variables.

[image]

`Airline_ID` is OK I believe since it is the primary key of the airline entity and is a foreign key in city entity . But why does `City_Name1` get created? Should it be created like this if I want to convert my logical model to a relational one? How can I create a relation without a duplicate variable created? I cannot delete it as well when I try to.

This is how my relation is configured :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should review your model because on picture you show one to many relation and you mention about m:n (many to many) relation.

In one to many relation main key from "one side"(airline table here) goes to the "many side" (city table here) and that is why you see airline_id on the city table (airline_id becomes foreigner key here). City_Name1 looks like some kinds of remains and you should delete it.